# How to replace Current script tag with HTML contents generated by the same script

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace the current script tag with the HTML contents generated by the same script.
That is, my Page is

```
 <html>
    <body>
       <div>
         <script src="myfile1.js"></script>
       </div>
       <div>
         <script src="myfile1.js"></script>
       </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Inside each .js file corresponding html contents are generated. I want to put the contents as the innerHTML of the parent div. But can't set id for the parent div because the page is not static. So the current script tag must be replaced with the HTML content. How can I do this?

For each script tag src is the same. So can't identify with src. These scripts displays
some images with text randomly. Scripts are the same but displays different contents in divs on loading

Please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try inside of myfile1.js:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName( "script" );
for ( var i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++ i )
{
   if ( scripts[i].src == "myfile1.js" )
   {
      scripts[i].parentNode.innerHTML = "new content";
   }
}
```

Comment: myfile1.js has already done what it needed to do at that point.  You can just rip it out and expect anything to come with it.  It won't remove global variables or un-document.write anything.

Comment: edited. `scripts [i].parentNode` returns `<div>` tag. To change content You can use `innerHTML` or DOM functions.

Comment: This is a good solution if you are always certain that the script is in the DOM at runtime. 

However, how would you do this if the script tag were added after the document was loaded, assuming that the script were added before another script tag?

Answer (score 3):

This is a great question for those trying to implement a JSONP widget. The objective is to give the user the shortest possible amount of code.

The user prefers:

```
<script type="text/javscript" src="widget.js"></script>
```

Over:

```
<script type="text/javscript" src="widget.js"></script>
<div id="widget"></div>
```

Here's an example of how to achieve the first snippet:

```
TOP OF DOCUMENT<br />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
// inside of widget.js
document.write('<div id="widget"></div>');
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://test.com?remote_call=1', function(data) {
        $('#widget').html(data);
    });
});

<br />BOTTOM OF DOCUMENT
```

Have a look at: http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/ for the correct way to include a library inside of a script.

Answer (score 1):

`document.currentScript` has been available since 2011 on Firefox and 2013 on Chrome.

[document.currentScript documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>currentScript test</title>

<h1>Test Begin</h1>

<script>
  document.currentScript.outerHTML = "blah blah";
</script>

<h1>Test End</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

*poof* -- old answer gone.

Based on your last edit, here's what you want to do:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <!-- I recommend getting this from Google Ajax Libraries
             You don't need this, but it makes my answer way shorter -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
             function getRandomContent(){
              // I expect this is the contents of your current script file.
              // just package it into a function.
              var rnd = Math.random();
              return "[SomeHtml]";
             }
             $('.random').each(idx, el){
                 $(this).html(getRandomHtmlContent());
             });
          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="random">
       </div>
       <div class="random">
       </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a running JavaScript file is not aware of where it is running. If you use document.write() in the script, the write function will take place wherever the script runs, which would be one way to accomplish what you want, but without replacing the contents or being able to perform any actions on the enclosing DIV.

I can't really envisage a situation where you'd have such stringent restrictions on building a page - surely if the page is dynamic you could generate identifiers for your DIV elements, or load content in a more traditional manner?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Smarty?

http://www.smarty.net/

You can use javascript in Smarty templates, or just use built-in functions.

Just take a look at http://www.smarty.net/crash_course

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind the script tag remaining in place you can use something as simple as document.write().

myfile1.js:

```
document.write("<p>some html generated inline by script</p>");
```

It will do exactly what you need.

Comment: I think he means that, if you have `<div><script src="s.js"></script></div>` and s.js file is `document.write("<p>new content</p>")` you'll get `<div><p>new content</p></div>` - quite simple

Comment: @John Green - PageSpike: Sir, the idea is so basic that I don't think it requires any code. When you want a script to render something exactly where you place it, let alone the reasons for such requirement, document.write is just the way to go. Anyway there is exactly the same suggestion in a post below. For the sake of your own consistency please downvote it too.

Comment: @John: Nope, it's still there. Obviously everyone can see where you're coming from with such boolean hatred for document.write. I could say I come from a place near you, however I'm pretty sure you neither understand the question, nor the solution, nor the way it's equivalent to finding script's own parent and appending html to it. Personally I don't care getting downvotes, however I can only hope you won't cause too much harm to those newbie people who actually believe you and your random superstitious comments.

Comment: The only post below is one about Smarty.  I think I get the solution, since was modifed ex post facto be a veritable clone of my own.  My goal in being here is to help people.  That doesn't necessarily mean coddling them with the line of code they need, because there's more to it than that.  I took issue with your code, because it seemed that was what the author was attempting to do in the first place, which was really what I had a problem with in the first place.  But I digress... I've been over the top, and I apologize.

Comment: Seems we have posts sorted in a different order. I was referring to M1ke's answer, who said that document.write could do. Again, let alone sensibility of the author's requirement. I use to say that it's best to answer questions that have been actually asked. There is often too much a story behind every piece of code posted here, so I simply don't bother unveiling why one would need something this way or another. Assuming the author doesn't mind keeping the script tags where they are instead of removing them, document.write (regardless of its barbarian looks) will just do what he wants.

Comment: To back this approach, imagine a month from now, for some reason we can't anticipate or change, somebody needs to write html with javascript at the place where the script executes. He finds this question in a search engine, but instead of finding out how to do it he will find how to use jQuery to put some content into 2 divs by class name.